# How to convert 0-3 V (PWM range) to 0-24 V (device voltage requirement)

Tags: arduino, voltage, voltage-regulator, pwm, solenoid

I have an Arduino with some PWM pins, output range is **0 to about 3 V** and I need **0 to 24 V** range.

I need to active a solenoid -  a hydraulic proportional solenoid

A 12V and 5V source is also available but, *the final output (0 to 24V) must be controlled by the Arduino output (0-3V)* .... for example, Arduino: 1V => output: 8V

Comment: What do you need to do with this 0-24V output? It matters whether you just need it to be a voltage SIGNAL (voltage only, zero current) or whether you need it to actually provide current to power something.

Comment: @DKNguyen i need to active a solenoid.... A Hydraulic Proportional Solenoid

Comment: Is it bidirectional?

Comment: @DKNguyen As I asked a company, there also bidirectional types (and as seems, I need a bidirectional one)

Comment: @DKNguyen I added some details to first post

Comment: `I need to active a solenoid...` I don't think an Arduino alone will help you with that. You'll need a transistor to help you drive the load.

Comment: You can modify an inexpensive, adjustable buck or boost converter: remove the potentiometer, add one or two resistors and drive the input from a DAC. As the Arduino has not DAC, you would need a separate one (on a break-out board or similar) or switch to a MCU with a DAC. If you are interested, I can give you details how to calculate the resistors so get the full 0 to 24V range.

Comment: @DKNguyen , Can you explain a little more..... I'm amature in Electronics...

Comment: Just one thing.... the range is importatnt.... I mean I need 0 to 24v and at 0 the output must be 0v to not cause solenoid to be active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find an easier way

Use a Motor Driver Module

It also support Reversing Voltage (reverse motor rotation)

Answer (score 2):

This circuit here will allow a low-voltage signal to PWM switch a higher voltage source through a load. If you actually need to reverse polarity through the load (such as to drive something like a DC motor in reverse, the you will need an H-bridge instead).

You may also replace the NMOSFET with an NPN BJT, especially if you can't find a logic level MOSFET. A base resistor will be required for the BJT.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f65O3n.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>